# Excel Services Sharepoint 2010 removes macros from xlsm file

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I am using Excel Services in Sharepoint 2010 to inject some data into an Excel xlsm file.  This is working fine.

I know that macros will not run on the Sharepoint server, but I want users to be able to download the full workbook after the data injection and have the macros enabled in the full workbook. But, it seems that when Excel Services injects the data, the workbook is always saved with the macros stripped out of the file.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

How does Excel Services "inject" data? Consider using a data connection in the Excel file instead.

To do that, create a view that shows the data you want and export to Excel. The file now has a data connection to the SharePoint list. You can configure the connection settings and use the data in the spreadsheet. You can hide the sheet with the SharePoint data if it messes up the workbook look.

Or, use the file "injected" with Excel Services as a source file and create a separate file that runs the VBA. Open the injected file and read its data with VBA.

Comment: Thanks, but for security reasons the end user is not allowed to receive a file with an active connection. Essentially, we have a system whereby we paste the results of an MDX query into the file as a plain table. It is also not feasible in this particular case to use two separate files as per the second suggestion.

Comment: Again, how does Excel Service "inject" data into the file? Can you describe what you mean by that?